# sending capl message with m.FDF bit set

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I am trying to send a message on a simulated CANoe bus. I want to set the FDF bit for can fd. In the capl node that outputs the message, the FDF bit is set. But as soon as the receiver reacts to the message in his 'on message' routine, the FDF bit is no longer set.

There is no database with signals etc. used.

```
// receiver
int examineCanMode(message *m){
  if (m.FDF == 0){
    return CLASSIC_CAN;
  }
  if (m.FDF == 1){
    return CAN_FD;
  }

  write("DUT: ERROR in examineCanMode.");
  return ERROR;
}
```

Does someone know what to do?
kind regards, Michael

Comment: Are you sure the bus you are trying to output it to is set to CAN-FD?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Virtual CAN, go to the **Hardware** ribbon and select **Network Hardware**.
Select your CAN Channel in the left pane and select **ISO CAN FD** under **Mode** option.
This will make the virtual channel as an FD channel.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration is enough.
For ex. Message Name is Diag_Message then:

```
 Diag_Message.FDF=1;
```

It will send the Message in CAN FD Frame.And yes Hardware settings also has to done